# HTTPWebrequest-upload and read file in server

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-upload, httpwebrequest

Is there any method  which will helps to upload files with HTTPWebrequest?

I had gone through this [site](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/12/16/posting-multipartform-data-using-.net-webrequest.aspx/) which describes about HTTPwebrequest.

My requirement is I have an upload window, when the user selected any excel file that has to be read without saving the content to the server. Currently Im using OLEDB to read the data. But to use OLEDB the file should exist in the server.

HTTPWebrequest can use in this case? or any better approach?
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: There is always `WebClient.UploadFile`

Comment: Is it possible to get the file details from Browser(from the end user)? what are the prerequisites for that?

Comment: Do you mean through a File Select Dialog? Yes, just pass it the local file name and the url